# How do I know if my current apple account is developer or enterprise one

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning, in-house-distribution

Our client has enrolled for an apple developer program. They claim they have enrolled for Enterprise program. But when we login with admin credentials, We see items missing specific to enterprise programs like, no option to create In-House distribution certificate. How can I know if the account is enterprise one?

Answer (score 27):

[image: Go inside Membership tab and check as shown in image for your membership detail. Enterprise will be shown as "Apple Developer Enterprise Program]

Go inside Membership tab and check as shown in image for your membership detail. Enterprise will be shown as "Apple Developer Enterprise Program

Answer (score 5):

Go into the app developer portal and click on "Program & Add-Ons" and in "Program Summary" it should state if you have enterprise or just apple developer program (apple enterprise should say: "Apple Developer Enterprise Program").

Comment: It says, Account Type: Company/Organization.

Does this mean Individual (Organisation) or Enterprise (Organisation)?

Comment: Apologies, go to "Program & Add-Ons" and in "Program Summary" it should state if you have enterprise or just apple developer program.

Comment: It says 'Apple Developer Program' - Does this mean this is developer an not enterprise? Can you tell me what text will appear incase if its enterprise account?

Comment: It should say: "Apple Developer Enterprise Program"

Comment: Thanks @Danny . Can you also share a screenshot capture of the text to your answer. Would help others to relate quickly.

Answer (score 3):

An enterprise account should have the In-House option when creating a new Distribution provision profile or a new Production certificate. If you do not have these options then it's probably not an enterprise account.

Also, when you go into the Member Center (where you have links to SDKs, Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles, Forums, etc.) you should see a link to "Enterprise and IT" and not to "iTunes Connect" as you would on a regular developer program.

Finally, when you go into "Your Account" on the member center (top toolbar), you should see under "Membership" the program type: "Apple Developer Enterprise Program".